# org.reflections doesn't load internal class marked with annotation from inside a jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

When attempting to load a class's method with an annotation from within a jar file (they are both in the same file) in eclipse java will load the required class and run all the methods with the annotation. However when I export the project as a jar it will instead not load the annotated method. I am using org.reflections and jdk1.8.0_131 (Maven is not being used due to issues with certain methods).
The code to load the methods:

```
Wrapper.out.println("Checking for boot tasks.");
    Data.setLoad_stage(61);
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder().setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage("app")).setScanners(new MethodAnnotationsScanner()));
    Data.setLoad_stage(62);
    Set<Method> methods = reflections.getMethodsAnnotatedWith(InitializationEvent.class);
    Data.setLoad_stage(63);
    for(Method m : methods) {
        Data.setLoad_stage(64);
        try {
            Wrapper.out.println("Running " + m.getDeclaringClass().getName() + "." + m.getName() + " : " + Integer.toHexString(m.hashCode()));
            Data.setLoad_stage(65);
            m.invoke(null);
            Data.setLoad_stage(66);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
            Data.setLoad_stage(67);
            e1.printStackTrace();
            Data.setLoad_stage(68);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
            Data.setLoad_stage(69);
            e1.printStackTrace();
            Data.setLoad_stage(70);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e1) {
            Data.setLoad_stage(71);
            e1.printStackTrace();
            Data.setLoad_stage(72);
        }
    }
```

InitializationEvent:

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
```

@Target(METHOD)
public @interface InitializationEvent {

}

setLoad_stage - changes the value of the loading bar.